# Detect if sensors are available on a Windows 8 device

Tags: gps, windows-8, windows-runtime, sensors

How to detect if a sensor is available on a Windows 8 device? My app needs GPS to work properly, so I need a way to detect if it is available on the device it is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some available sensors for Windows 8 devices.

you can check if they are available by GetDefault() method. It returns 'null' if the sensor is not available.

```
if(Accelerometer.GetDefault() != null)
{
    // your code
}
if (Compass.GetDefault() != null)
{
    // your code
}
if (Gyrometer.GetDefault() != null)
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the LocationStatus property of the Geolocator object... if it is NotAvailable or Disabled you are out of luck...

Comment: I've tried that. My laptop doesn't have GPS ;) but the status is shown as `NoData`, instead of `Disabled` or `NotAvailable`. Since `NoData` can be the status even if GPS sensor is present, it poses a problem.